# How to plot 1d scatterplots by category/ or add points over a boxplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot, boxplot

I currently have this boxplot implemented using pandas reading in data from a database.

My example is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymysql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

experiments = ['exp1', 'exp2', 'exp3']
test_data = pd.DataFrame({ "value":np.random.normal(0.8,0.2,20)} )
test_data["name"] = np.random.choice(experiments, size=20)

test_data.boxplot(column='value', by='name', figsize=(15,12))
```

[image: boxplots]
This isn't exactly what I was going for though, I really want to display all points on the graph in a scatter.

An example of the output I want was found in another question, but I lack the skills to correctly apply it to my dataframe which is not in the same format....:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ "A":np.random.normal(0.8,0.2,20),
                      "B":np.random.normal(0.8,0.1,20), 
                      "C":np.random.normal(0.9,0.1,20)} )

data.boxplot()

for i,d in enumerate(data):
    y = data[d]
    x = np.random.normal(i+1, 0.04, len(y))
    plt.plot(x, y, mfc = ["orange","blue","yellow"][i], mec='k', ms=7, marker="o", linestyle="None")

plt.hlines(1,0,4,linestyle="--")
```

[image: boxplot with scatter]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_boxplot.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
test_data.boxplot(column='value', by='name', figsize=(15,12))

for i, (k,d) in enumerate(test_data.groupby('name')):
    y = d['value']
    x = np.random.normal(i+1, 0.04, len(y))
    plt.plot(x, y, mfc = ["orange","blue","yellow"][i], mec='k', ms=7, marker="o", linestyle="None")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's generally considered a bad practice to have visual elements of a data visualization to be generated by (even seeded) random numbers.

Comment: The code with `np.random.normal(i+1, 0.04, len(y))` simply adds jitter to the points such that they are visually distinguishable along the horizontal and don't clump together. So should be okay